# Is the complement of a set of ordered pairs $U \times U$? or just $U$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are sets in a universal set $U$, and we define the complement of set $A$ as $\overline{A} = U \setminus A$.

Which of the following two is true about the complement of the cartesian product of set $A$ and set $B$?

$\overline{A \times B} = (U \times U)\setminus(A \times B)$?

Or,

$\overline{A \times B} = U \setminus (A \times B)$?

or does it not really matter and either are okay, because $U$ is the "universal set", so it includes anything?

Comment: What do you mean by $A$ and $B$ being "universal sets in $U$"?

Comment: sorry, $A$ and $B$ are sets in a universal set $U$.. i will fix it

Comment: For the latter, $A\times B$ is not even a subset of $U$, so it doesn't really make sense to write that.

Comment: Okay, thanks that was what i was asking, if you make an answer I will accept it

Comment: We can't just assume $U$ is universal in the sense that it contains every set ([set of all sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set)). If we did, we would run into Russell's Paradox.  However, we could try to specially construct a set $U$ so $U$ has whatever we need, and that $U = U \times U$.

Comment: @TokenToucan How do you know $A \times B$ is not a subset of $U$? That depends on $A,B$ and $U$.  In any case, $U \backslash (A \times B)$ is still fine to write.

Comment: @JairTaylor it is still essentially a type error (and require a very special set) and I would argue not fine to write in general. Such set theoretic coincidences (that UxU and U are might not be disjoint) are kind of pathological and certainly not the kind of tricky point to emphasize to someone who is just learning.

Comment: @TokenToucan Fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $U = \{ 0,1 \}$, $A = \{ 0 \}$ and $B = \{ 1 \}$. Then $$U \times U = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) \}$$ What is $(U \times U) \setminus (A \times B)$? It's exactly $U \times U$ take away all the sets in $A \times B = \{ (0,1) \}$; thus $$(U \times U) \setminus (A \times B) = \{ (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) \} $$

What about $U \setminus (A \times B)$? This time you consider $U = \{ 0,1 \}$ and you take away the elements in $A \times B$; but no element of $A \times B$ is in $U$, so $U \setminus (A \times B) = U$.

---

Make sure the sets you are working with are of the same "type" (this is informal). Set theory is very precise (what pure math isn't?), and it most certainly matters what the terms you use mean. In this case, note that $U \neq U \times U$, which leads to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C:= A \times B.$ Then $C$ is a subset of $U \times U.$ Hence

$$\overline{A \times B}= \overline{C} = (U \times U)\setminus C= (U \times U) \setminus(A \times B).$$